# Connecting to a SQL Server instance on a VM using Windows Authentication mode

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, windows-authentication

I've got a small program I'm writing that I need to be able to point at a SQL Server instance that is on a virtualbox VM's (not Azure). Unfortunately when these VM's are created the SQL Server instances are installed with Windows only authentication. We use the same credentials for each VM, however they are not on our domain (where the program would be running)

I know that the typical connection string for windows authentication has `Integrated Security=SSPI` in it but is it possible to specify the windows credentials for the VM you're connecting to in the connection string?

Is there anyway around this? Setting up SQL authentication is not really an option. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: This http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/trusted-connection-from-a-ce-device/ implies that you can pass the windows credentials in, but I've never believed it or managed to test it before. If this works for you please post back.

Comment: I'm going to try it, but I think that is only for Windows CE devices so I'm not holding out too much hope using that connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question has already been answered. Following 2 links might be helpful

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/john_paul_cook/archive/2010/02/26/using-windows-authentication-from-a-non-domain-joined-machine.aspx

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66014/connect-to-sql-server-with-windows-authentication-in-a-different-domain?lq=1

Comment: If `RunAs` is a valid solution this might also be required. http://codebetter.com/jameskovacs/2009/10/12/tip-how-to-run-programs-as-a-domain-user-from-a-non-domain-computer/